# How to implement venmo payment in braintree payment

Tags: braintree, venmo

Venmo - Braintree payment

Venmo option not showing in Payment Methods. Please look at the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Need only a US account for this. Issue Resolved. But another issue is Venmo button not showing in Dropin list.